# Parse text/html part of email source using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, email, mime

Using javascript, I need to parse the Content-Type `text/html` portion of an email message and extract just the HTML part. Here's an example of the part of the mail source in question:

```
------=_Part_1504541_510475628.1327512846983
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


<html ... a bunch of html ...

/html>
```

I want to extract everything between (and including) the `<html>` tags after `text/html`. How do I do this?

NOTE: I'm OK with a hacky regex. I don't expect this to be bulletproof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on RFC/MIME documentation, *the encapsulation boundary is defined as a line consisting entirely of two hyphen characters ("-", decimal code 45) followed by the boundary parameter value from the Content-Type header field*.

**Note:** In JavaScript there is indeed no `/s` modifier to make the dot `.` match all characters, including line breaks. To match absolutely any character, you can use character class that contains a shorthand class and its negated version, such as `[\s\S]`.

---

***Regex:***

```
\n--[^\n\r]*\r?\nContent-Type: text\/html[\s\S]*?\r?\n\r?\n([\s\S]*?)\n\r?\n--
```

***JavaScript:***

```
matches = /\n--[^\n\r]*\r?\nContent-Type: text\/html[\s\S]*?\r?\n\r?\n([\s\S]*?)\n\r?\n--/gim.exec(mail);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Ωmega is close but you can't be sure that the boundary contains the `-` character.

You first need to look within the headers. The headers and body of the actual email content will be separated by `\r\n\r\n`. You should see a header something like

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="------=_Part_1504541_510475628.1327512846983"
```

This boundary is what you can then use to find the actual divider. You can then construct a regexp just like Ωmega's but substitute in this divider.

The only thing to be aware of is that the last boundary will have `--` at the end in addition to the normal boundary content.

Comment: Steve, I have edited my answer with note from documentation - boundry has to start with at least two `-` characters...

Answer (score 2):

```
var html = source.toString().substr(source.toString().indexOf("\n\n")).trim();
```